# Lombok causing MapStruct compileJava build failure after upgrading to Gradle 5.0

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, lombok, mapstruct

We are trying to upgrade from Gradle 4.5 to 5.0. After upgrade, compileJava is failing because Mapstruct is not able to resolve values (getters not available obviously) used in @Mapping annotation. This was working fine in Gradle 4.5 .

The code is like this

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public interface CAndACodeGenConverter extends BaseConverter<CGen, AGen> {

    @Mapping(target = "owner", source = "owner.name")
    @Mapping(target = "useCA", source = "defaultCA")
    AGen convertToDto(CGen entity);
}
```

Our build.gradle is like this

```
    mapstructVersion = "1.4.1.Final"
    lombokVersion = "1.18.12"
    lombokMapstructBindingVersion = "0.2.0"

    compileOnly('org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.12')
    compile("org.mapstruct:mapstruct:${mapstructVersion}")
    implementation "org.mapstruct:mapstruct:${mapstructVersion}", "org.projectlombok:lombok:${lombokVersion}"
    annotationProcessor "org.mapstruct:mapstruct-processor:${mapstructVersion}", "org.projectlombok:lombok-mapstruct-binding:${lombokMapstructBindingVersion}"
```

The error we are getting is

```
error: No property named "owner.name" exists in source parameter(s). Did you mean "null"?
```

This was working fine in Gradle 4.5 .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try to change dependencies order like below:

```
compileOnly "org.projectlombok:lombok:$lombokVersion"
compileOnly "org.mapstruct:mapstruct:${mapstructVersion}"
annotationProcessor "org.projectlombok:lombok-mapstruct-binding:0.2.0"
annotationProcessor "org.mapstruct:mapstruct-processor:${mapstructVersion}"
annotationProcessor "org.projectlombok:lombok:$lombokVersion"
```

I've tested it just now and it works.

P.S. IDK why this order is required, got it from lombok-mapstruct-binding related article long time ago